# Embedding and sending HTML emails from Gmail

Tags: gmail, html

What is the best way to send out formatted HTML emails from Gmail?

Comment: This question was originally posted on Super User before the launch of Web Applications SE. Questions of "What is the best way..." are not being allowed as it's poor wording for the type of questions that we are looking for. In 2013, the site's About page was replaced by what is now known as the [tour]. Also, the directions about how to ask questions were updated a long time ago. See [ask]. Old questions that don't meet the quality standards, sometimes called "broken windows" are being closed because people might wrongly use them to ask new questions.

Answer (score 3):

I had a friend to use [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com).

She said it was easy to use and free.

Answer (score 2):

Some good reading: http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/2009/01/23/09.27.00/

Remember that a lot of email clients strip CSS, add funny declarations, implement user styles, and break everything in general. Your best bet is to style it like a normal web page, and add a large "Having trouble viewing this email? `View it online`" where `View it online` is a link to the online version.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail will send out HTML-formatted e-mail with a text/plain alternative included for older clients (or people with plain text preference) that know how to handle that sort of thing. Making a highly-customized HTML e-mail in Gmail is harder, but you can enable "Inserting images" on the Gmail Labs page to get a little closer to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Mailchimp is full featured but for a basic email Pablo's solution with Gmail is working fine. Just make sure "rich formatting" is enabled when you compose the mail